# i have a cart object in my order table need to display the items

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hello i have a cart object in my order table field so i need to display the order items but i cannot figure out how to display the items to unserialize object to array or some thing.

my object is like

```
"O:8:"App\Cart":3:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:4;a:3:{s:3:"qty";i:1;s:5:"price";i:44;s:4:"item";O:11:"App\Product":26:{s:13:"\x00*\x00connection";s:5:"mysql";s:8:"\x00*\x00table";N;s:13:"\x00*\x00primaryKey";s:2:"id";s:10:"\x00*\x00keyType";s:3:"int";s:12:"incrementing";b:1;s:7:"\x00*\x00with";a:0:{}s:12:"\x00*\x00withCount";a:0:{}s:10:"\x00*\x00perPage";i:15;s:6:"exists";b:1;s:18:"wasRecentlyCreated";b:0;s:13:"\x00*\x00attributes";a:20:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:8:"prodname";s:7:"GE GSWF";s:15:"proddescription";s:303:"<p><span style="color:#212529;font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum is a dummy text </span><span style="color:#212529;font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum is a dummy text</span></p>";s:4:"slug";s:9:"ge_gswf14";s:11:"gall_images";N;s:13:"feature_image";s:14:"1536994278.png";s:8:"brand_id";i:2;s:11:"category_id";i:2;s:5:"price";i:44;s:12:"manufacturer";s:10:"SmartWater";s:8:"features";s:123:"Delivers clean, clear water that looks and tastes great, Reduces sediment, lead, cysts, and turbidity in your water and ice";s:6:"height";s:8:"10 Meter";s:5:"width";s:5:"Meter";s:6:"length";s:7:"4 Meter";s:10:"itemweight";s:6:"10 lbs";s:10:"shipweight";s:6:"12 lbs";s:10:"fridgecomp";s:62:"Fridge Compatibility Fridge Compatibility Fridge Compatibility";s:6:"status";s:7:"publish";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2018-09-15 06:51:18";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2018-09-15 06:51:18";}s:11:"\x00*\x00original";a:20:{s:2:"id";i:4;s:8:"prodname";s:7:"GE GSWF";s:15:"proddescription";s:303:"<p><span style="color:#212529;font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum is a dummy text </span><span style="color:#212529;font-family:Montserrat, sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:600;text-align:center;">Lorem ipsum is a dummy text</span></p>";s:4:"slug";s:9:"ge_gswf14";s:11:"gall_images";N;s:13:"feature_image";s:14:"1536994278.png";s:8:"brand_id";i:2;s:11:"category_id";i:2;s:5:"price";i:44;s:12:"manufacturer";s:10:"SmartWater";s:8:"features";s:123:"Delivers clean, clear water that looks and tastes great, Reduces sediment, lead, cysts, and turbidity in your water and ice";s:6:"height";s:8:"10 Meter";s:5:"width";s:5:"Meter";s:6:"length";s:7:"4 Meter";s:10:"itemweight";s:6:"10 lbs";s:10:"shipweight";s:6:"12 lbs";s:10:"fridgecomp";s:62:"Fridge Compatibility Fridge Compatibility Fridge Compatibility";s:6:"status";s:7:"publish";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2018-09-15 06:51:18";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2018-09-15 06:51:18";}s:10:"\x00*\x00changes";a:0:{}s:8:"\x00*\x00casts";a:0:{}s:8:"\x00*\x00dates";a:0:{}s:13:"\x00*\x00dateFormat";N;s:10:"\x00*\x00appends";a:0:{}s:19:"\x00*\x00dispatchesEvents";a:0:{}s:14:"\x00*\x00observables";a:0:{}s:12:"\x00*\x00relations";a:0:{}s:10:"\x00*\x00touches";a:0:{}s:10:"timestamps";b:1;s:9:"\x00*\x00hidden";a:0:{}s:10:"\x00*\x00visible";a:0:{}s:11:"\x00*\x00fillable";a:0:{}s:10:"\x00*\x00guarded";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"*";}}}}s:8:"totalQty";i:1;s:10:"totalPrice";i:44;} ◀"
```

and i save this object like below in my order table

```
        $order = new Order();
        $order->cart = serialize($cart);
        $order->fname = $request->input('fname');
        $order->lname = $request->input('lname');
        $order->address1 = $request->input('address1');
        $order->address2 = $request->input('address2');
        $order->zip = $request->input('zip');
        $order->state = $request->input('state');
        $order->city = $request->input('city');
        $order->payment_id = $charge->id;
```

Comment: show me your code where you generated this type of object

Comment: $order = new Order();
            $order->cart = serialize($cart);
            $order->fname = $request->input('fname');
            $order->lname = $request->input('lname');
            $order->address1 = $request->input('address1');
            $order->address2 = $request->input('address2');
            $order->zip = $request->input('zip');
            $order->state = $request->input('state');
            $order->city = $request->input('city');
            $order->payment_id = $charge->id;

Comment: @RahulPawar i just save my $cart object in db with order

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using model [casts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting).

This will automatically **serialize/unserialize** fields which you specify in the array.

In your case, add this to the `Order` model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'cart' => 'array',
];
```

Comment: i need to show order item o my single order page so my controller have this code right now please advice.

`public function getordersingle($id) {
        $order = Order::find($id);

        return view('backend/orders/single')->withOrder($order);
    }`

Comment: so the order variable i have all details but i cannot figure out how i can loop through my items from variable $order->cart in my single order view

Comment: I think the first solution would be to not save the entire cart model, and only save what is needed. That will make the structure clearer. You won't need to `serialize()` this data if you are using casts.

Comment: but its not saving when in remove the serialize from my cart variable

Comment: When saving to the cart, I would suggest actually passing what is needed e.g. an array of cart items, rather than the `Cart` model itself.

Comment: so i can separate the array of $cart->item from my $cart

Comment: Yes, or `items` depending on how your relationship works. I can't see a reason why you would need to bring the entire cart. If you need to bring in the total price etc, just add them as separate keys to the `items` array.

Comment: how to separate the array help   `$cart = new Cart($oldCart);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180512/discussion-between-thisiskelvin-and-tehseen-ahmed).

Comment: currently when i dd($cart) i have the following items in my cart `Cart {#262 ▼
  +items: array:3 [▼
    4 => array:3 [▶]
    19 => array:3 [▶]
    5 => array:3 [▶]
  ]
  +totalQty: 3
  +totalPrice: 102
}`